# Python Regex Cannot get expression to match

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string from which I wish to extract a value. The string is: 'data - hk = "136 HK"'. I know, that data - hk = will always precede the value, hence I can use simple python str.split(). It is not a neat solution. I would like to get more familiar with regex, but my attempts have so far failed.

Here is what I have tried:

```
        text = 'data - hk = "136 HK"'
        
        # With simple text split - returns 136
        int(text.split("data - hk = ")[1].split('"')[1].split(" HK")[0])

        # With regex - returns nothing
        re.search("[\n\r].*data - hk:\s*([^\n\r]*)", str(text))
```

Can someone guide me to, what I need to change in the regex?

Comment: It could be something like `re.findall(r'^data - hk = "(\d+) HK"', text)`. But would the captured substring always be an integer? Looks like it by your own attempt at split.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it will always be an integer

Comment: I forgot the end string anchor in my previous comment. @Rva92. Did it end up working for you?

Comment: yes it did, thank you very much. Post it as answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you can just validate your string and extract your integer using `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'^data - hk = "(\d+) HK"$', text)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvTFOB/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `data - hk = "` - A literal match for mentioned string.
- `(\d+)` - A capture group to retrieve the integer of 1+ digits.
- `HK"` - Another literal match for mentioned string.
- `$` - End line anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
data - hk\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lyGmbp/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  data - hk                'data - hk'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

[**Code**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolatYwVZBPSWxJFFBVyEjG8hRMjQ2U/DwVlLnyk0sSc4AihSl6hWnJhYlZ2gUIVTGuGhpxKRoa9hbxegBaU17TXUdhWJNrsw0BYi@zGKFvPwSBb/8vFQrLgUgKCjKzCvRAEvqpRfllxZoGGpq/v8PAA):

```py
import re
s = 'data - hk = "136 HK"'
match = re.search(r'data - hk\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', s)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(1))
```

**Results**: `136`.